# Count different "spaces" between a given number

Tags: php, calculated-field

I have a line with numbers as a String:

```
$numbers = x, 5, 7, x, 9, 4, x, 3, 9, 5, x, ...
```

Now I want to count the "duration" between the x.

'x' appears:

```
2x times after [2] numbers
1x times after [3] numbers
```

I just can't figure out, which method in php is the best to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no method which does this for you, you'll have to program your own logic. **Hint:** use loops.and the `explode()` function.

Comment: Hey Daan, currently I'am going manually through the list, thought there is maybe a solution in php for this. Edit: Thanks for the tip with explode and the loops - will check it out!

Comment: `foreach()`, `explode()` and use a counter in a `switch()` or `if()` statement? Or produce a **callback** method, just some suggestions

Comment: Thanks guys, that's great help for me! Will test it out and hopefully post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the numbers are always 0-9 you could remove the commas and spaces and use strpos to find out where the x's are. No explosions needed.

```
$numbers = 'x, 5, 7, x, 9, 4, x, 3, 9, 5, x';
$string = str_replace(', ', '', $numbers);

$index = 0;
$previousPosition = 0;
$positionDifferences = array();

while($index < strlen($string)){
    $index = strpos($string, 'x', $index);
    $diff = $index - $previousPosition;
    $positionDifferences[] = $diff;
    $index++;
    $previousPosition = $index;
}
```

now `$positionDifferences` will hold an array with all the differences between the occurances of 'x'. In this example: `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )`